# Flask-SQLAlchemy Class / Table Many to Many relation - table not found

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

**Help needed...** 
i kind of figurered out that it is bad style to define a relational "helper" table as a class, but want to use it to store some information, that belongs there and access it conveniently
what am i doing wrong? When i set it up as a table i dont run into any issues...

Thanks!

```
from alexa import db


# Relation tables


class Todos(db.Model):
    _tablename_ = 'todos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                         db.ForeignKey("order.id"))
    sequence = db.Column(db.Integer)
    step_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                        db.ForeignKey("step.id"))

    orders = db.relationship("Order",
                             backref=db.backref("todos",
                                                cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
    steps = db.relationship("Step",
                            backref=db.backref("todos",
                                               cascade="all, delete-orphan"))

# Actual tables


class Vehicle(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True)
    customer_number = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    orders = db.relationship("Order", backref="order_vehicle")


class Order(db.Model):
    _tablename_ = 'order'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False, nullable=False)
    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("status.id"))
    vehicle_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("vehicle.id"))


class Step(db.Model):
    _tablename_ = 'step'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False, nullable=False)
    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("status.id"))

    comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("comment.id"))


class Status(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False, nullable=False)
    steps = db.relationship("Step", backref="step")
    orders = db.relationship("Order", backref="order_status")


class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(2000), unique=False, nullable=False)
    step = db.relationship("Step", backref="step_comment")
```

**My Error:**

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 507, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: order
```

**...**

```
    context)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 507, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: order [SQL: 'SELECT "order".id AS order_id, "order".title AS order_title, "order".status_id AS order_status_id, "order".vehicle_id AS order_vehicle_id \nFROM "order" \nWHERE "order".id = ?\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'] [parameters: ('1', 1, 0)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: Urgency of a question is relative - and it's very bad style to assume ones own problem more important than the problem of an arbitrary other person asking a question for whatever other reasons he or she may have. In essence: indicating urgency usually does not help you a single bit - on the contrary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - should have specified ;)

Comment: The error itself should be pretty clear: your SQLite database does not have that table. Have you ran `create_all()` or done anything to add the table after adding that model?

Comment: You've btw. mistyped `__tablename__` as `_tablename_`, but that's not causing the error.